# html button element to load preformatted test to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I want a button where:

- `onmousedown` loads preformatted text into a textarea element, and
- `onmouse` up saves that same preformatted text to the clipboard to be pasted into a document.

---

```
<textarea name="REMARKSTEXTAREA" id="REMARKSTEXTAREA" rows="1" cols="100">   </textarea>

 <input value="preformatted text" 
   onmousedown="function(loadtext);"
   onmouseup="copy_to_clipboard('REMARKSTEXTAREA');" 
   type="button">
 <script>
 function(loadtext)
 {
   var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
   mytextbox = "preformatted text";
 }
 function copy_to_clipboard(id)
 {
   document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA').select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: `function(loadtext)` <= your function has no name, so you can't call it. Try defining it as `function loadtext()`, and in your HTML, do `onmousedown="loadtext();"`. Then, inside the function, do `mytextbox.value = "...";`

Comment: Still not working...  :(

Comment: What exactly is the point of saying 'Still not working'? If you want help you need to learn how to describe a bug http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html so people have some hope of being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **blex** in the comments:

```js
function loadtext() {
  var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
  mytextbox.value = "preformatted text";
}

function copy_to_clipboard(id) {
  document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <textarea name="REMARKSTEXTAREA" id="REMARKSTEXTAREA" rows="1" cols="100"></textarea>

  <input value="preformatted text" onmousedown="loadtext()" onmouseup="copy_to_clipboard('REMARKSTEXTAREA');" type="button">
</body>

</html>
```